# umbraco front end site stopped working suddenly

Tags: umbraco

I created one webapplication and placed the default.aspx page in the root folder of the umbraco (i.e., httpdocs folder) and the application dll into the bin folder.

I used the name “Default.aspx” as the other names are not working.

Now the issue is all the pages are redirecting to the default.aspx page (I haven’t made any config changes anywhere in the umbraco setup)

I found this root cause and removed the default.aspx page and its respective dll from the bin folder.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /default.aspx

I stuck up here and struggling to resolve it.Please help me out on this

THanks,
Srilakshmi

Comment: I'd say the first step is a look into the error file and finding out which resource was requested exactly (full path) when the 404 occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the 'republish website' option by right-clicking on the top level content folder icon after logging into Umbraco as an admin?

Comment: Yes i tried that option - republished entire site but of no use :(

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - and I know this is an old question - but this happens when default.aspx has been either overwritten, deleted or otherwise changed so that it doesn't call umbraco.UmbracoDefault.  Just make sure that default.aspx contains only the following code :

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="default.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="umbraco.UmbracoDefault" trace="true" validateRequest="false" %>
```

Thought this might help others as I overlooked it today with a similar problem :)